# proof of equality condition for Holder's inequality for $p=1, q=\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Assume $u\in L^1(\mu)$ and $v \in L^\infty(\mu)$, then $\int |uv| d\mu = \Vert u \Vert_1 \Vert v \Vert_\infty$ iff $v|_{\{u \neq 0\} } \equiv \Vert v\Vert_\infty$ a.e.

I'm trying to show the only if direction. This is my attempt.

Let $A:=\{u\neq 0\}$. Then we have $\int |uv|d\mu = \int |u|\Vert v\Vert_\infty d\mu$, so 
$\mathbb{1}_A(x)|u(x)|(\Vert v\Vert_\infty - |v(x)|)=0$ a.e. Since on $A$, $|u(x)|>0$, we must have $\Vert v\Vert_\infty = |v(x)|$ a.e. on $A$.

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: I would just include "$\|v\|_\infty-|v|\geq 0$ a.e. on $A$". Then you can conclude "$\int 1_A|u|(\|v\|_\infty-|v|)d\mu = 0 \Rightarrow |u|(\|v\|_\infty-|v|)\equiv 0$ a.e. on $A$". But your arguments seems fine to me.